# np.einsum multiplication of matrices with several indices?

Tags: numpy, numpy-einsum

Given m x n matrix A and n x r matrix B how to write the following formula in `np.einsum` notation?

```
f(i) = \sum_{j,k} a_ij * b_jk
```

What will change in `np.einsum` if r x p matrix C will be added?

```
f(i) = \sum_{j,k,l} a_ij * b_jk * c_kl
```

Comment: 'sum_{j,k} a_ij * b_jk' should use 'ij,jk->i'

Comment: thanks! and for 3 matrices it seems to look like np.einsum("ij,jk,kl->i", a, b, c)

Answer (score 1):

@Sengiley Despite you already answered yourself's question. A more general version that allows broadcasting is:

```py
np.einsum('...ij,jk,kl->...i', a, b, c)
```